# Why is Content-Type: image/jpeg header not working?

Tags: php, gd, gd2

I'm using GD library to resize image. Why is not `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` working?

It gave me an error as you can see in pic below:

[image: Error screenshot]

Here are my GD details:

[image: my GD version].

```
<?php  
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
if(isset($_GET['image'])){ 
    $image = $_GET['image'];
    list($image_width, $image_height)= getimagesize($image);
    $new_size = ($image_width+$image_height)/($image_width*($image_height/45));
    $new_width = $image_width * $new_size;
    $new_height = $image_height * $new_size;

    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $old_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

    imagecopyresized($new_image, $old_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);
    imagejpeg($new_image);
}
?>
```

Comment: Most possibly there is other output prefixing your image - whitespace or PHP warnings. Open the defective image in a text or hex editor and take a look.

Comment: You are getting an error in your PHP code, and that error is trying to be rendered as an image.  Remove the `header` line for now, and see what gets printed to the page.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck, thank so much. it was defective image. i don't know why print screen images are defected. i tried on image from google, it's working fine. you saved my day.

Answer (score -1):

It would always better to use the existing scripts/libraries instead of reinventing the wheel... try using timthumb or similar... that would save a lot of time and error free...

http://www.phpguy.in/simple-way-to-generate-thumbnails-in-php/