# Content-Type: image/jpeg not working on live working on local

Tags: php, image, content-type, slim

I am very new to slim framework and i am trying to download a image file. Working fine on local with php . But when applying same code on server for slim its not working . Searched a lot But no luck i.e [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148586/php-header-content-type-image-jpeg-not-working-for-internet-explorer) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410195/why-is-content-type-image-jpeg-header-not-working). here is my code

```
$app->get('/image', function ($request, $response, $args) {
//header('Content-type: image/png');
//header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=go-logo.jpg');
//$contents = file_get_contents(getcwd() . '/' . $_GET['img']);
$filename=getcwd() . '/' . $_GET['img'];
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=go-logo.jpg');
readfile($filename);
return $contents;

});
```

[image]

Error is it is showing it is a html file . i want like this

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by not working? `$contents` is also not defined anywhere.

Comment: sorry . i forgot to attach screenshort

Comment: please check it now

Comment: Did you downloaded the image and open with an editor? It might be an error page that server is giving.

Comment: yes image is downloaded . hitt this link http://slim.eaglecoders.website/image?img=generator/1471887174.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the headers on the response object.
Then write the file to the Response body.

```
return $response->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
        ->write($fileContents);
```